# "a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined" error despite including the correct c++/winrt headers

Tags: c++, winrt-xaml, c++-winrt

I am trying to convert a small win32 desktop app for consumption of c++/winrt components and XAML islands. I have followed the numerous article on the subject and have indeed been able to compile and run the application with some basic XAML controls. My problem arose when using FileOpenPicker and the subsequent error message indicating that "a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined". I have seen others have solved this by including the relevant header files but I have already done that and I am still getting the error.

I have included the header files ;  - I tried including in the pch file and in the source file itself.

```cpp
#include "pch.h"

#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.Pickers.h>

#include "360MediaPlayer.h"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::UI;
using namespace Windows::UI::Composition;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Hosting;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Numerics;
using namespace Windows::Storage;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Pickers;
using namespace Windows::Media::Playback;


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HWND _hWnd;
HWND _childhWnd;
HINSTANCE _hInstance;

HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    _hInstance = hInstance;

    // The main window class name.
    const wchar_t szWindowClass[] = L"Win32DesktopApp";
    WNDCLASSEX windowClass = { };

    windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    windowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    windowClass.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    windowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);

    //windowClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(windowClass.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (RegisterClassEx(&windowClass) == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Windows registration failed!", L"Error", NULL);
        return 0;
    }

    _hWnd = CreateWindow(
        szWindowClass,
        L"Windows c++ Win32 Desktop App",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );
    if (_hWnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Call to CreateWindow failed!", L"Error", NULL);
        return 0;
    }



/*    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_MY360MEDIAPLAYER, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    */

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MY360MEDIAPLAYER));


    // The call to winrt::init_apartment initializes COM; by default, in a multithreaded apartment.
    winrt::init_apartment(apartment_type::single_threaded);

    // Initialize the Xaml Framework's corewindow for current thread
    WindowsXamlManager winxamlmanager = WindowsXamlManager::InitializeForCurrentThread();

    // This DesktopWindowXamlSource is the object that enables a non-UWP desktop application 
    // to host UWP controls in any UI element that is associated with a window handle (HWND).
    DesktopWindowXamlSource desktopSource;
    // Get handle to corewindow
    auto interop = desktopSource.as<IDesktopWindowXamlSourceNative>();
    // Parent the DesktopWindowXamlSource object to current window
    check_hresult(interop->AttachToWindow(_hWnd));

    // This Hwnd will be the window handler for the Xaml Island: A child window that contains Xaml.  
    HWND hWndXamlIsland = nullptr;
    // Get the new child window's hwnd 
    interop->get_WindowHandle(&hWndXamlIsland);
    // Update the xaml island window size becuase initially is 0,0
    SetWindowPos(hWndXamlIsland, 0, 200, 100, 800, 200, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);

    //Creating the Xaml content
    Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::StackPanel xamlContainer;
    xamlContainer.Background(Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::SolidColorBrush{ Windows::UI::Colors::LightGray() });

    Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBlock tb;
    tb.Text(L"Hello World from Xaml Islands!");
    tb.VerticalAlignment(Windows::UI::Xaml::VerticalAlignment::Center);
    tb.HorizontalAlignment(Windows::UI::Xaml::HorizontalAlignment::Center);
    tb.FontSize(48);

    MediaPlayer mpSphere = MediaPlayer();


    FileOpenPicker foPicker = FileOpenPicker();
    StorageFile file(foPicker.PickSingleFileAsync().get());

    mpSphere.SetFileSource(file);
    mpSphere.Play();

//  xamlContainer.Children().Append(tb);
    xamlContainer.UpdateLayout();
    desktopSource.Content(xamlContainer);

    //End XAML Island section

    ShowWindow(_hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(_hWnd);


    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

So the full error messsage I'm getting is the following:

> Error C3779   'winrt::impl::consume_Windows_Foundation_IAsyncOperation<winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<winrt::Windows::Storage::StorageFile>,TResult>::get': a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined'

despite the presence of the header files as can be seen above. If I remove the code dealing with the Media file and leave only the XAML stuff, it runs. Anyone know what I'm missing? I can provide the full project if needed.

Comment: Narrow it down to a [mcve] please. That must be one of the first steps in your debugging process, before you resort to asking for help! _"If I remove the code dealing with the Media file and leave only the XAML stuff, it runs."_ Then a good start is to abstract away everything but the code dealing with the Media file.

Comment: Did you already read this article: [Why does my C++/WinRT project get errors of the form “consume_Something: function that returns ‘auto’ cannot be used before it is defined”?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190530-00/?p=102529)? It should help you to figure out what header is missing. You should also show us the whole error message so that we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

`auto` Keyword simple ask the compiler at compilation time to deduce the type with whatever you are type to use it as, maybe a return from a function, or a hard coded POD type like an int.

the issue with your code is your missing your include for winrt foundation, which is required for your code since its accessing Async functions, honestly most WinRT code requires the include for foundation

```
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
```

since you forgot to include the foundation include, the compiler had no way to deduce the type for which the error was thrown.....

please note that auto keyword is great for functions in the form of trailing return types, but i highly suggest you don't use them for variables for a number of reasons, a few notable ones being odd bugs with vector iterators, where even when included properly, inside a template function the auto keyword wont be able to deduce the type and will cause an error,

```
template <typename T>
auto findSomething(:std::string name)
    -> T*
{
    // the code here causes an error since we are trying to deduce the var inside a 
    // template function using auto
    auto _Found = ::std::find_if(somevector.begin(), somevector.end(), [&](::std::pair<::std::string, ::std::unique_ptr<class Someclass>>& pair){ return (pair.first = name) ? true : false; });

    if(_Found != somevector.end())
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(_Found->second.get());
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Corrected

```
template <typename T>
auto findSomething(:std::string name)
    -> T*
{
    ::std::vector<::std::pair<::std::string, ::std::unique_ptr<class Someclass>>>::iterator _Found = ::std::find_if(somevector.begin(), somevector.end(), [&](::std::pair<::std::string, ::std::unique_ptr<class Someclass>>& pair){ return (pair.first = name) ? true : false; });

    if(_Found != somevector.end())
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(_Found->second.get());
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

if your dont want to type `::std::vector<::std::pair<::std::string, ::std::unique_ptr<class someclass>>>::iterator` every time simply type alias your type wit the `using` keyword `using myvectortype = ::std::vector<::std::pair<::std::string, ::std::unique_ptr<class someclass>>>` that way you only need to type `myvectortype::iterator`....

hope this helped you fix your code.

Comment: That did it Daniel! Thanks!

Comment: @scalpel im happy it did (=, also would you mind marking this as the answer for your question since it solved your problem, thanks and have a awesome day (=

Comment: The important point here is, that C++/WinRT uses return type deduction **without** a trailing return type. You'll find details in the duplicate question (and answer).

Comment: @IInspectable yes it is important to note that, and i even mentioned it as i said the compiler could not deduce the type without the correctly provided header file, which while not implicitly saying is pretty much saying is saying that, i just mentioned the trailing return types, and not using auto for variables to help the OP understand the mechanics behind the auto keyword and its functionality better since he seemed rather new to the concept (=